# How to zoom image while anchoring it in a specific corner?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, zooming

I'm experimenting with the CSS zoom property, and I'm trying to basically zoom into an image while keeping it anchored at a certain point. So rather than zooming in while the point at 0,0 stays put, I'd like it to zoom from the bottom right corner instead.

So this is my attempt, but obviously it's a little "quirky":

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/nJ2M8/

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div class="square">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/800" width="400" height="400" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.square img').on('click', function() {
    $('.square').animate({
        zoom: '200%',
        left: '-200px',
        top: '-200px'
    }, 200);
});
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.square {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    background: #333;
    vertical-align: bottom;

    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Impact, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Any way to get this to behave as I'd like it to? I need the 400,400 corner to stay put as it zooms in.

Comment: Checkout my alternate solution below, based on the user click location.

Comment: Using `zoom` is a terrible idea, because Firefox/Opera don't support it.

Comment: That is a solid point. I was merely pointing out that 'event' can be used to manage the user's click location (specifically in response to @CaptSaltyJack 's post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to zoom to the center of the image then change:

```
    left: '-200px',
    top: '-200px'
```

To:

```
    left: '-50%',
    top: '-50%'
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJ2M8/1/

### Update

Try using `transform`, it's capable of scaling an element. Here is some code I wrote a while ago to do just this:

```
$(function () {
    var venderTransform = ($.browser.webkit)  ? 'WebkitTransform' :
                      ($.browser.mozilla) ? 'MozTransform' : 
                      ($.browser.msie)    ? 'MsTransform' : 
                      ($.browser.opera)   ? 'OTransform' : 'transform'


    $('.square').each(function () {
        $.data(this, 'scale', 3);
    }).bind('mousewheel', function (event, delta) {
        event.preventDefault();
            
        var sc = $.data(this, 'scale');
        
        if ((delta == 1 && sc < 5) || (delta == -1 && sc > 1)) {
            sc += delta;
            $.data(this, 'scale', sc);
            $(this).children('img').css(venderTransform, 'scale(' + sc + ')');
        }
    }).bind('mousemove', function (event) {
        var sc = $.data(this, 'scale') || 1;//scale
        if (sc > 1) {
            var $this = $(this),
                X  = (typeof(event.offsetX) == 'undefined') ? (event.pageX - $this.offset().left) : (event.offsetX),//current cursor X position in bullet element
                Y  = (typeof(event.offsetY) == 'undefined') ? (event.pageY - $this.offset().top) : (event.offsetY),//current cursor Y position in bullet element
                w  = 400,//width of thumbnail
                h  = 400,//height of a thumbnail
                nX = ((w / 2) - X),//new X
                nY = ((h / 2) - Y),//new Y
                tf = 'translate(' + (nX * (sc - 1)) + 'px, ' + (nY * (sc - 1)) + 'px) scale(' + sc + ')';//transform string
            $this.children('img').css(venderTransform, tf);
        }
    }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
        
        //reset .has-thumb element on mouseleave
        $.data(this, 'scale', 3);
        $(this).children('img').css(venderTransform, 'translate(0, 0) scale(1)');
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJ2M8/2/ (the zoom follows your cursor and you can use your mouse-wheel to zoom in/out)

Comment: Nope, as I said I'd like to zoom into the bottom right corner. But I used -100% and -100% as values and that worked. Wouldn't have thought to use percentages. Thanks!

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack Check-out the **update** to my answer. Using `transform` is the HTML5 way to scale and translate an element.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that thoroughness. What's with the MozTransform, WebkitTransform, etc? I thought those CSS props were -moz-transform and -webkit-transform, respectively?

Comment: Oh and what is the advantage of using transform vs zoom?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack I would stay away from `zoom` because it's an Internet Explorer non-standard property. I'm not 100% sure of the browser support but it doesn't look good: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom. `transform` is new in CSS3, is quite powerful and it's how to be forward-thinking. Full browser support requires checking for `transform` support, using CSS for those browsers and JavaScript for others (you can do this with `zoom` as well).

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack I forget exactly what it's called but `WebkitTransform` is the DOM version of `-webkit-transform`. In JavaScript we can change styles using this: `document.getElementById('some-element').style.WebKitTransform = 'rotate(45deg) scale(2) translate(10px, 10px)'`, since `.style.-webkit-transform` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery to the following

```
$(".square img").click(function(e){
      $('.square img').animate({
        zoom: '+=.5'
      }, 600);
      $('.square').animate({
        left: '-=' + e.pageX,
        top: '-=' + e.pageY
      });
});
```

This will allow you to zoom in where the user is clicking.